# Beetle with long, slender iridescent green body and orange legs

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I recently saw this beetle while on a trip in central Texas, USA (in a rural area just before sundown). The body was about 2-3 inches long (compare to nearby chair leg and floorboards) and had a long body. It was very vivid green, and its upper legs were very bright orange (which made me wonder if this is aposematism). Its antennae had very uniform half-circle arcs (instead of the uneven parabolic shape often seen in cockroaches and similar common insects) and didn't seem to bend besides being rotated ~5 degrees up and down.

It carried itself pretty high off the ground, perhaps half an inch between the belly and ground-level. It seemed to move fairly fast, but not as fast as a cockroach. It didn't fly in the few minutes I observed, and didn't seem like it could fly since the shell appeared solid, but I might have mistaken well-fitting sheaths for fused ones.

[image]

What is the most likely species? Is it poisonous?

Comment: I can't see the antenna well, but they look long. Could it be some sort of [longhorned beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longhorn_beetle)?

Comment: @user137 For anyone wondering, the antenna were quite long - all of the blurry blackish line is antenna. Based on my recollections, if I pulled on them and straightened, they would be between 1.25 and 1.5 times the length of the beetle's body - consistent with your answer as well!

Comment: With this image, I've had one bite me, after maybe 6 hours a blister began to form. I believe it's a blister beetle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to guess it's an Plinthocoelium suaveolens, based on the image found [here](http://bugguide.net/node/view/307334/bgimage), which I show below:

[image]

I found this link through a Texas beetle page [here](http://texasento.net/TXBycidPix.html) and is the best I can do from the image provided.